# Having listed items change color when selected

Tags: html, css

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SMftA/2/

I want the background-color of mon changed if it's selected. If it's not selected it should be the color it was initially created with.

I'm not sure why this doesn't work.

I'm thinking the issue is with mon having a class and an id?

```
    <li id="mon" class="selected">Mon</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a selector specificity issue here.  The ID selectors take precedence over the class selector.  To remedy this issue you could add an ID to your UL and create a higher specificity for your selected class like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/8MQSu/

HTML:

```
<ul id="day-container">
    <li id="mon" class="selected">Mon</li>
    <li id="tue">Tue</li>
    <li id="wed">Wed</li>
    <li id="thu">Thu</li>
    <li id="fri">Fri</li>
    <li id="sat">Sat</li>
    <li id="sun">Sun</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#chooseDays{
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:250px;
}

#mon{
    background-color:#D1F7CE;
    clear: none;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#tue{
    background-color:#FCF4BB;
    clear: none;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#wed{
    background-color:#F7D0CE;
    clear: none;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#thu{
    background-color:#CED2F7;
    clear: none;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#fri{
    background-color:#CEF6F7;
    clear: none;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#sat{
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    clear: none;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#sun{
    background-color:#FFE6F4;
    clear: none;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#day-container .selected
{
    background-color:#000;
}
```

Comment: This will allow you to have the same background-color for each selected list item without specifically having to list out CSS rules for #mon.selected, #tue.selected, etc

Comment: Thanks! That worked better than the all class solution. I prefer IDs if it's only being used once in code.

Comment: I think using `id's` for styling isn't the best way. I read some articles about it. Here you can find one of them: http://oli.jp/2011/ids/. But ofcourse it's your decision which way you choose.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you typing first background color for id `#mon` which is strongest in css rules than class typing. Here You can see when it work:

http://jsfiddle.net/SMftA/3/

I will also edit your jsFiddle and show how to make this working well.

### EDIT

I change your id's to classes. Now you have less lines and this should look that:

http://jsfiddle.net/SMftA/4/

Comment: Good to hear that. You use solution with class `day`? or just fix with adding id before `.selected`?